# How does memory get allocated in a for(prop in obj) loop and what is the best approach

Tags: javascript

I have the following snippet

```
for(var prop in windowManager.owners) {
    if(windowManager.owners.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        if(windowManager.owners[prop] instanceof WhatAmILookingFor) {
            if(windowManager.owners[prop].id=== lookupid) {
                return windowManager.owners[prop];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Would it be better to store the reference to `windowManager.owners[prop]` in a temp variable like this?

```
var win = null;
for(var prop in windowManager.owners) {
    if(windowManager.owners.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        win = windowManager.owners[prop];
        if(win instanceof WhatAmILookingFor) {
            if(win.id === lookupid) {
                return win;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Are there benefits of doing it this way? Would there be gc overhead by doing it this way? Or would it have no impact on gc because the `win` object gets reused?

What would be the best course of action?

I do realise we are talking about microseconds here in speed difference, i'm just interested in the "behind the scenes" actions, like the way the memory gets allocated/reused and what would be best practise memory wise.

Comment: If you declare `win` outside of 'for' loop lexical scope, it will persist, keeping memory allocated for it, until process leaves current scope (incl. for loop and anything going after that), which, imo, makes this code a bit less memory efficient.

Comment: Use the variable because it makes it easier to read, not because of micro-optimization considerations.

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin 'for' loop in javascript doesn't create a new scope, so the variable will have the same life span whether it is declared inside or outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The second loop is faster since it doesn't traverse the same object over and over again.

```
windowManager.owners[prop]
```

means "look up `windowManager` in the current scope, then find a property `owners` and then a slot `prop` inside of that". Because of the complex rules which JavaScript uses to locate properties, it's expensive.

The second problem is typos. If you compress such complex expressions to a local variable, you reduce the chances of typos. Imagine someone replaces `prop` with `prop2` and misses 1 in 3 - this actually happens a lot.

Lastly, it makes the code more readable plus you can use this approach to express intent by giving the variable a name which explains why it's there.

Memory wise, the difference isn't that big. Even when `win` is at the global level, it's just a reference to an existing object (= a few bytes). It could cause a leak, though. So it might be wise to set it to `null` after the loop or wrap the whole code in a function to make sure it's cleaned up.

Comment: Since OP uses `return` in his code, we can expect this to be in a function already, so it's cleaned up properly even without setting anything to `null`.

Comment: @Bergi: Make sense. I just wanted to make it clear that it could be a potential memory leak.

Comment: Well if `windowManager` is not a leak already, then `win` wouldn't be either :-) But you're right, one can never warn enough about global variables.